# How can you embed a C++ game into a webpage?

Tags: c++, embed

Without recoding in flash or making it into a java applet! *Keeping it as a C++ app*, is there a way to embed it into a web page so site visitors can play the game?

We can assume it's a small game, the size of your average flash game or even thinner.

The game in question was written with the Allegro library in under 1000 lines of code.

Is it possible?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/native-client/devguide/tutorial

Comment: I believe, if you implement a JavaScript C++ interpreter/compiler or compile C++ code into JavaScript code, you can do that.

Comment: @Alex: in principle you can do that in two steps without having to implement anything for yourself: Comeau compiles C++ to C, and then Clue (http://cluecc.sourceforge.net/) compiles C to Javascript. Disclaimer: this might not actually work, I don't know whether Clue accepts every C feature that Comeau outputs, I don't know how browser-portable the output of Clue is, and (most importantly) since pure C++ has no GUI, this particular app surely uses platform-specific libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick answer: **no** you can't.

C++ applications cannot be embedded inside a web page, they need to be downloaded and the user has to run them on the client machine.

Details: it's somehow possible but it's absolutely **not portable across browsers**. For example Internet Explorer has **ActiveX** components (they can be a C++ application, it'll be downloaded, installed and will run inside the web-page). Other browsers have different mechanism to achieve this (Chrome has its **Native Client**, for example) but you can't write something really portable and you'll have many limitations whatever you'll use.

Comment: Using Emscripten you can generate cross browser Javascript code!

Comment: Interesting project! I would never ever write anything in C++ to _compile_ it to JavaScript but idea itself is funny.  Nowadays there are also other viable alternatives but some rewriting is always required. If emscripten works in your case then good catch!!!

Answer (score 3):

It is possible

http://doom.pdox.net/

http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/

In fact, this is old news...

http://www.engadget.com/2010/05/13/googles-native-client-sdk-developer-preview-provides-helpful-re/

Comment: It works but it'll run only on Chrome and probably he'll need to change his code.

Comment: In-browser Doom is amazing :D

Answer (score 3):

Try the emscripten project, it is a C++ compiler based on LLVM Clang and compiles C++ files into JS files which can then be run in the browser.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Assuming that you saved this in `helloWorld.cpp` use this after installing Emscripten.

```
$ emcc helloWorld.cpp -o helloWorld.html
```

You will be done, open `helloWorld.html` now in your browser and see for yourself. The good thing about Emscripten is that it supports a wide range of desktop libraries, including SDL etc.,

http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/

Comment: Emscripten can do it while the app is
-Cross platform
-The library you are using support's OpenGL ES 2 or your using OpenGL ES 2 compatible OpenGL code!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible only as plugin for Google Chrome browser as native extension.